# multiline comment() attributes for functions

Tags: r, function, comments, attr

Say I have the following function:

```
sqrt_x = function(x) {
     sqrtx = x^0.5
     return(list("sqrtx" = sqrt))
}  
attr(sqrt_x, "comment") <- "This is a comment to be placed on two different lines"
```

if I type

```
comment(sqrt_x)
```

I get

```
[1] "This is a comment to be placed on two different lines"
```

what I want, however, is that the comment is returned on two different lines (it could also be more lines and different comment elements. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: `comment(sqrt_x) <- "my comment"` is a cleaner way to specify the comment.

Comment: thx, however, it doesn't give me more liners,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrie stated: you need to insert newline characters.

If you don't want to have to manually specify where the newlines go, then you can use `strwrap` to create breaks at convenient points, so that your string doesn't exceed a specified width.

```
msg <- strwrap("This is a comment to be placed on two different lines", width = 20)
cat(msg, sep = "\n")
# This is a comment
# to be placed on two
# different lines
```

---

A complete solution could look something like:

```
#Add comment as normal
comment(sqrt_x) <- "This is a comment to be placed on two different lines"

#Display using this function
multiline_comment <- function(x, width = getOption("width") - 1L)
{
  cat(strwrap(comment(x), width = width), sep = "\n")
}

multiline_comment(
  sqrt_x, 
  20
)
```

Comment: well, i don't want to type cat(comment(sqrt_x)) in my console, that's a little awkward. I want source files to have some quick form of commenting, so that others can quickly type: comment(function) and get a quick and brief help text info. However I would like it to have some structure to it.

Comment: The edit is great and it is what I was really asking for. It's a bit of a workaround, but for internal uses perfekt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\n` to insert a newline. The `cat` method shows this in the way you want:

```
attr(sqrt_x, "comment") <- "This is a comment to be placed on two\ndifferent lines"
cat(comment(sqrt_x))

This is a comment to be placed on two
different lines
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, and maybe not what you want, but if you provide a multi-element `character` vector, and the lines are long enough that R's default formatting decides they should be on multiple lines, you may get what you want:

```
comment(sqrt_x) <- c("This is a comment                       ",
                     "to be placed on two different lines")
comment(sqrt_x)
## [1] "This is a comment                       "
## [2] "to be placed on two different lines"
```

You could use `format` to pad automatically:

```
comment(sqrt_x) <- format(c("This is a comment",
                            "to be placed on two different lines"),
                             width=50)
```

(as shown elsewhere you could also use `strwrap()` to break up a single long string
into parts)

If you're absolutely desperate to have this and you don't like the extra spaces, you could mask the built-in `comment` function with something like @RichieCotton's multiline version:

```
comment <- function(x,width = getOption("width") - 1L) {
   cat(strwrap(base::comment(x), width = width), sep = "\n")
}
```

but this is probably a bad idea.